# Jmeter email notification configuration

Tags: jmeter

For notification mail in jmeter I was following the steps from https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter.

But I was not able to get the result after executing the test. Please find the screen shot I have attached to know what all configuration I have done in the SMTP sampler.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbtoZ.png)

Please let me know what all I need to add here to make it run successfully.

Comment: Please share what is the error or the problem you face.

Comment: the error is:

Thread Name: tearDown Thread Group 1-2 Sample Start: 2017-03-14 11:54:42 IST Load time: 2834 Latency: 0 Size in bytes: 4 Headers size in bytes: 0 Body size in bytes: 4 Sample Count: 1 Error Count: 1 Response code: 500 Response message: AuthenticationFailedException: authentication failed - wrong username / password! javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials j14sm1178407itd.0 - gsmtp

Response headers:

SampleResult fields: ContentType: DataEncoding: null

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is your SMTP Request Sampler configuration:

[image]

According to [Google SMTP Configuration instructions](http://Read%20Gmail%20messages%20on%20other%20email%20clients%20using%20IMAP) given you use port `587` you need to tick `Use StartTLS` radio button.

Alternatively you can change the port to `465` and tick `Use SSL` button.

I don't think Gmail will accept non-encrypted messages. Please read [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) once more and be more attentive as correct configuration is mentioned there:

[image: Blazemeter JMeter Smtp Sampler Gmail correct configuration]